# How to send multiple input field values with same name?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have m2m field, lets say it have name 'relations', so i want to allow user to send as many relations as he wants. I add new input to html with javascript with same name, like so

```
<input type='text' name='relations' value='a' />
<input type='text' name='relations' value='b' />
```

in cleaned_data i receive only value of second input ('b'). How to receive both?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't know how to do that with Forms, but if you want to grab the values in the raw way, here's how I'd do:

```
relations = request.POST.getlist('relations')
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to grab all the raw values, you can just get the specific data by using element name like this:

```
relations = request.form.getlist('relations')
```

That will return a list of values in the `relations` input.

Comment: There's no 'request.form' in Django 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

this generate a list, you can manipulate in for

```
request.POST.getlist('relations')
```