# How to receive the posted values of textbox array in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have array of textboxes like this

```
<input type="text" value="" name="key[]" />
<input type="text" value="" name="key[]" />
<input type="text" value="" name="key[]" />
```

in python access the posted value as

```
keys = postDict['key[]']
```

when I print the value of the variable keys it prints only last textbox value. How to receive the posted value as list or array.

### Problem

The problem is I'm appending the textbox to div with the name **key** when a button named **MORE** is clicked. Form is **not posting the runtime generated textbox** values.

Comment: This question has already been addressed.Follow this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478382/how-to-send-multiple-input-field-values-with-same-name

Answer (score 1):

Don't call the field `key[]`. That's a PHP-ism.

Use `request.POST.getlist('key')` to get all the values.

Comment: Still im getting last value only

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel says, use request.POST.getlist('key') to get all the values. BUT, from your comment it sounds like the name of the field you're trying to get the data for is the same for all elements, in which case .getlist() is just returning the last one it can get its hands on. (The same would happen with .get() ).

So, Django IS receiving the raw data you want, but is squashing it when you try to .get() it because of a key clash.

Is there anything stopping you using different names for each text input? If not, I would go down that route, as it's saner overall.

PS - the PHPism in your example made me think you're pretty new to Django. If this is the case, check out this great guide to the [Django forms library](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/)