# Django multiple input field values with same name

Tags: python, django, forms

I need some help. How can I handle the form ,with multiple input field values, with same name? and only once view, this actually for basic questions form.. another idea I found this method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/478406/6396981:

```
relations = request.POST.getlist('relations')
```

[image: django questions form]

How do I handle it all? Currently I'm doing it with `<input type="radio"...`, but of course it couldn't work if it has same name in once form. But if I use: `<input type="checkbox"...`, the answers can be check more than 1 in once question...

Maybe like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="answer-{{ question.id }}">
```

How can I get it all in the view?

**Solved:**

In my test:

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="{{ question.id }}/>

    {% for answer in question.get_answers %}
        <input type="radio" name="answer-{{ question.id }}" value={{ answer.score }}>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`views.py`

```
questions = request.POST.getlist('question')
answers = [request.POST['answer-{}'.format(q)] for q in questions]
```

And the results of it:

```
['20', '19', '16', '13', '11', '10', '9', '8', '1']
['5', '2', '3', '4', '1', '4', '4', '2', '2']
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Checkboxes and radio buttons are *supposed* to have more than one option with the same input name. What exact problem are you experiencing? And why aren't you using the Django forms API?

Comment: how i can do with Django forms with dynamically, if have many questions?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you right you need to implement multiple choice?
Then you can do in your template this:

```
{% for answer in answers %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer" id="answer{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ answer.id }}">
{% endif %}
```

Andi in view:

```
answer = request.POST.getlist('answer')
for el in answer:
    pass
```

Comment: previously i doing same with this.. but only once answer which successfully saved...