# Quiz sytem model Field selection

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a model for the Quiz-system in Django.There is Question and 5 options for each question.

```
    class Question(models.Model):
      quiz_question=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
      option1=models.CharField(max_length=500)
      option2=models.CharField(max_length=500)  
      option3=models.CharField(max_length=500)
      option4=models.CharField(max_length=500)
      option5=models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Here only one answer is the right answer.Which is the best way to represent the answer here? Is it by adding another field or is it can be done by editing one of the existing field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few months ago, I has similiar django project bassed on Question system.
In your case, I think you need to create a new `Answer` model that   `ForeignKey` to the `Question` model.

Here is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db.models import (Q, Count, Sum)
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible


class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class QuestionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Question(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('short', _('Sort')),
        ('medium', _('Medium')),
        ('complete', _('Complete'))
    )
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
        default='short'
    )
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = QuestionQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def total_score(self):
        answer = Answer.objects.filter(
            question__pk=self.pk
        ).annotate(Sum('score'))
        return answer  # .count()

    def get_answers(self):
        return Answer.objects.filter(
            question__pk=self.pk
        )
    get_answers.allow_tags = True

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Detail Question')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Questions')
        ordering = ['-created']


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, related_name='question_answer'
    )
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField()


def key_generator():
    import uuid
    key = uuid.uuid4().hex
    if BaseAnswerUser.objects.filter(key=key).exists():
        return "{0}-{1}".format(key, uuid.uuid4().hex)
    return key


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class BaseAnswerUser(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    To save the answers that already answered by user.
    in this case, is such as session method.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='user_answer'
    )
    key = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        unique=True,
        default=key_generator
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('result', kwargs={'key': self.key})

    def get_answers(self):
        return AnswerUser.objects.filter(
            base_answer__key=self.key
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return _('Result analyze for %(user)s') % {
            'user': self.user.username,
        }

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Base Answer User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Base Answer Users')
        ordering = ['-created']


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class AnswerUser(TimeStampedModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, related_name='question_answer_user'
    )
    base_answer = models.ForeignKey(
        BaseAnswerUser, related_name='base_answer_user'
    )
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    text_answer = models.TextField(
        null=True, blank=True
    )

    @property
    def weight(self):
        return self.question.weight

    def __str__(self):
        return _('Result for %(question)s') % {
            'question': self.question
        }

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Detail User Answer')
        verbose_name_plural = _('User Answers')
        ordering = ['-created']
```

To handle the answers in the dashboard django admin, I used `admin.TabularInline`. For more, you can checkout at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/agusmakmun/ff741854ac9f44c38ecec7badb1dc1ab)

> And see also how to handle [Django multiple input field values with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40784376/6396981)

Hope it helpful..

---

### Update

My previous answer is for dynamic answers system, an example:

1. Question A ***(has 4 option answers)***

   - a). Option answer A
   - b). Option answer B
   - c). Option answer C
   - d). Option answer D
2. Question B ***(has 3 option answers)***

   - a). Option answer A
   - b). Option answer B
   - c). Option answer C

---

If you implement a ***Static Answers*** system, this so far as I understand:

> The ***Session Answer User*** is represented as ***Base Answer User*** from my previous answer;

```
[ Question ] -------------------+
 - title       (chr)            |
 - description (chr)            |
 - weight      (int)            |
    |                           |
    |                           |
    |                           |
   \./                         \./
 [ Answer ]               [ Answer User ]
 - fk_question (int)      - fk_question       (int)
 - option_a    (chr)      - fk_session_answer (int)
 - scroe_a     (int)      - score             (int) # save the final score
 - option_b    (chr)           /'\
 - score_b     (int)            |
                                |
                                |
                                |
                      [ Session Answer User ]
                          - fk_user      (int)
                          - session_key  (char:unique)
                          - created      (date)
                                |
                                |
                               \./
                          [ User Model ]
                            - username    (chr)
                            - date_joined (date)
```

#### How about the queryset?

an example I want to find total scores for the specific user and specific session.

```
>>>
>>> session = get_object_or_404(SessionAnswerUser, user=request.user, session_key='key-key-key')
>>> answered_questions = AnswerUser.objects.filter(session_answer=session)
>>>
>>> # Find total scores. eg: {'score__sum': 15}
>>> answered_questions.aggregate(Sum('score'))['score__sum']
15
>>>
```

#### How and When you use `session_key` ?

> After the User answered all question *(create mode)*, then redirecting to the result page. an example:

```
@login_required
def save_answers(request):
    """
    This view isn't using django forms, 
    but only handling at the templates and this view.
    Because until now I don't know how to handle it.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # retrieve all id/pk's from the `questions` (model:Question)
        questions = request.POST.getlist('question')

        # retrieve all id/pk's from the `answers`. (model:Answer)
        answers = [request.POST['answer-{}'.format(q)] for q in questions]

        # saving the session with `key_generator()`, see my previous answer.
        session = SessionAnswerUser.objects.create(user=request.user)
        session.save()

        # Makesure the length of `questions` is same with length of `answers`
        # 1 answer for 1 question
        if len(questions) == len(answers):
            for n in range(len(questions)):
                dict_answer = {
                    'question': Question.objects.get(pk=questions[n]),
                    'session': session, # from latest session above
                    'score': answers[n]
                }
                answered_questions = AnswerUser.objects.create(**dict_answer)
                answered_questions.save()

            # redirecting to the result page.
            return redirect('/result/page', key=session.session_key)

        else:
            # length of `questions` is not same with length of `answers`
            # do stuff...


@login_required
def result_page(request, key):
    session = get_object_or_404(SessionAnswerUser, session_key=key)
    answered_questions = AnswerUser.objects.filter(session=session)

    # I hope you already know how to use the django queryset.
    # eg:
    # >>> session.user
    # <User: john smith>
    # >>> 
    # >>> answered_questions
    # <QuerySet: [<AnswerUser: foobar lorem>, <AnswerUser: xxxx>]>
    # >>> 
    # >>> answered_questions.first()
    # <AnswerUser: foobar lorem>
    # >>> answered_questions.first().score
    # 3

    ...
    # your context goes here..
```

Comment: Why I need t create another table here. I Think its a waste

Comment: previously, you need to save they answers or not?

Comment: yes, I want to save the ansewer. But is there anyway to show relationship between that one option and the question

Comment: also iam not an expert in the database models

Comment: your option fields is static or dynamic?

Comment: option fields is static